# Handling a Circular Queue that is Made Up of Objects

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, queue

I am trying to create a circular queue that will hold objects.  The idea is the user will either buy or sell stock, and each time a stock is purchased, that object will hold the amount of stock purchased and the price is was purchased for in the queue. This queue is an array based queue with a size of 32 and every time the user selects to buy, it will fill another slot. 
 If the user elects to sell stock, the number of stocks sold will be subtracted from the first object unless the user sells more stock than the first slot contains, in that case it will subtract from the subsequent slot. Once the slot has had all of it's stock sold...aka it has no more shares, that object can be dequeued and it will free up a slot to buy stock once the queue comes around to that position

I am struggling on handling the object types. Especially when I try to dequeue just for testing to see if I can dequeue properly.... I will get the last slot when I dequeue even though I am pretty sure the method is right, I am just having difficulty handling the classes/objects.

NOTE: I must manually create the array/queue, so I can't use the Java built in array

**StockTran class.......Has Stock as a nested class**

```
  import java.util.Scanner;

    //Once you reach the end of the array, you are going to get an out of bounds exception if you try to enqueue again
    //So if there are any open boxes on the very front of the array, say a[0] is empty, you can place the extra array spot at a[0]
    //Then keep going

    //You can handle the overflow and make the array circular or at least get the size by using (get + put)%size...So if (4+5)%8
    //the answer is 1... meaning the size is 1.

    //Create a total variable thats adds up the total of shares each spot in the array has...This way you can say you don't have
    //that many shares if they try to sell more than what you actually have....Also look at the amount of shares each spot has
    //and only dequeue when the total of shares for that spot is used up..."Only dequeue a truck when it's empty"


    //User is prompted to enter in either b, s, c, or q..... 
    //b = buy shares, s = sell shares, c = capital gain from buying and selling q = quit the program
    //Must be formatted by letter (space) number (space) number........ EX: b 10 10        .... this will buy 10 shares at $10 each      

    //This is the class I am storing in the queue.....Can call methods on it to get out crucial data
        class Stock {
        public int getShares() {
            return shares;
        }

public void setShares(int shares) {
    this.shares = shares;
}

public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}

private int shares;
private int price;

// Get price Get Shares set price get set price

public void stockTran() {
    // total gain,
}
}

 //Class that handles the user's input, should handle the math for profit, subtracting,       etc....Basically the class that
 //links all the other classes/methods together
 public class StockTran {

// Declaring variables
private MyQueue<Stock> queueArray;  // Size of Array/Queue is 32
static String firstCommand;         // The first token of the scanner...Looks
                                    // whether b,s, or c
static int shares;                  // How many shares that are bought/sold
static int price;                   // The price those shares are bought/sold at
static int netProfit = 0;           // Initializing the profit so it can be
                                    // added/subtracted later
static int put, get = 0;            // Declaring the front and rear portions of the queue

static int total = 0;               // Initial number of elements in the array, this will
                                    // increase/decr


public static void main(String[] args) {
    StockTran eg = new StockTran();

    eg.queueArray = new MyQueue<Stock>(32);
    Stock test = new Stock();

    // Prompts the user to enter an input

    // The if/else if ladder is used to call the correct methods based on
    // the user input..Reads by looking
    // at the tokens
    while (true) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the proper formatted commands ");
        firstCommand = reader.next();
        if (firstCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("b")) {
            shares = reader.nextInt();
            price = reader.nextInt();
            test.setPrice(price);
            test.setShares(shares);
            eg.queueArray.enqueue(test);

            System.out.println("Price: " + test.getPrice());
            System.out.println("Shares: " + test.getShares());
            System.out.println("Size: " + eg.queueArray.size());

            // System.out.println("Buying " + shares + " shares" + ", " +
            // "$" + price + " each");

        } else if (firstCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("s")) {

            System.out.println("dequeued price: " + ((Stock) eg.queueArray.dequeue()).getPrice());
            System.out.println("dequeued shares: " + ((Stock) eg.queueArray.dequeue()).getShares());

            System.out.println("Size: " + eg.queueArray.size());
        }

        else if (firstCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
            System.out.println("Capital gain");
        } else if (firstCommand.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
            System.out.println("Quitting");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Command Not Recognized!");
        }
    }
}

// This method will either add or subtract from the total profit depending
// upon the buying and selling....Not finished yet
public int calculate(int netProfit) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < shares) {

        i++;
    }
    return netProfit;

}
 }
```

**Queue Interface**

```
    public interface Queue <E> {

        //Gets the size of array queue
        public int size();

        //Checks if the queue is empty
        public boolean isEmpty();

        //Looks at the first item
        public Object front() throws EmptyQueueException;

        //Puts an element at the end of the array
    //  public void enqueue (Node element);

        public void enqueue (E element);


        //Removes an element from the front of the array
        public Object dequeue() throws EmptyQueueException;
    }
```

**MyQueue class**

```
        // Creates the node and allows methods to assign, get the next element, and set elements
        // for the node

        //So you create a node class with quanitity and price.... Has to be an object
        public class MyQueue <E> implements Queue <E>
        {
            //Instance variables
            private Object [] queue;
            private int front, rear = 0;   //Pointers for the queue....Locates where the next enqueue/dequeue spot should be
            private int max = 32;          //Size of my queue
            private int size;

            public MyQueue(int max)
            {
                this.queue = new Object[max];
            }

            @Override
            public int size() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                size = (rear - front)%32;
                return (rear - front)%32;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isEmpty() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (front == rear)
                    return true;
                else 
                    return false;
            }

            //Gets the front object of the queue
            @Override
            public Object front() throws EmptyQueueException {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        return queue[front];
            }

            //Adds an element to the end of the queue
            @Override
            public void enqueue(E element) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                this.queue[this.rear%this.max] = element;
                if (rear < 32)
                rear++;
                else
                    rear = 0;
                System.out.println("Font is: " + front);
                System.out.println("Rear is: " + rear);

            }

            //Removes an element from the front of the queue
            @Override
            public Object dequeue() throws EmptyQueueException {
                Object temp = null;
                if (isEmpty() == true){
                    throw new EmptyQueueException("Empty Queue!");
                }       
                if(size() > 0 && front != size){
                    temp = queue[front];
                    System.out.println(": " + temp);

                    front = front + 1;
                }
                    else if(front == size())
                     front = 0;

                System.out.println("Font is: " + front);
                System.out.println("Rear is: " + rear);
                return temp;

        }
        }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to execute it step-by-step under debugger and inspect the values you're storing and analyzing?

Comment: I realize the problem was I was only creating one object to store in the queue and I would keep updating that object with new values each time I wanted to put another object in the queue....So instead of creating new objects, I was just trying to reuse an old one...... So my Dequeue method works, I just need to figure out how to handle creating objects properly    For example: I was only using the variable test to point to an object...and I would update test with new values and try to place test into the queue into a new spot...Once I created test1, test2, test3 it worked